# why their should override super class parameterize constructor in sub class constructor when it extends from super class?

Tags: java, subclass, superclass

why the code `super(0)`  is needed in sub class constructor to compile when creating a sub class constrctor?

```
public class Super {
    public Super(int i) {
        System.out.println("super(int i)");
    }
}

class Sub extends Super{
    public Sub(int i) {
        super(0); // why this code needed here to compile?
        System.out.println("Sub(int)");
    }
}

class Demo{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sub s1=new Sub(100);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Super class should be constructed before constructing sub class.

Since the super class does not have a default constructor, so you have to call `super(0);` first.

You can add a default construtor in super class:

```
public Super(){}
```

then you do not need call `super(0);` in sub class.

Answer (score 0):

When Sub class extends Super class, all the members(*methods and variables only,constructor not a member*) in super class extends to Sub class.

From main method in class Demo called the Sub class Sub(int) constructor,
Then first statement in the Sub(int) constructor have super() call in Super class.It is automatically put java compiler.

**But above code haven't default constructor** (*because you write whatever constructor java compiler don't give default constructor automatically.you need no parameter constructor(default constructor) you have to write it manually*) So you need to write super(int) called manually. Because you wrote this constructor in Super class.
If not it is compile error.

Then output as following :

```
super(int i)
Sub(int)
```

Instead of above all class in one package you have to Demo class is public(Except Super class). Because It has main method.

Answer (score 0):

That's because in java every subclass need to call constructer of its super class. If you have a default constructer in super class than  you don't need to call that explicitly as java does that for you but if  you don't have any default constructor in superclass with no parameters but instead you have some constructer(s) with parameter(s) you need to call that in first line of your sub class constructor.